# Javascript Total Duration of Function Execution?

Tags: javascript

```
//this is a loop every 10 seconds it will run again and again.

function GetSomthing(){
    start = new Date().getTime()
    //do someting
    end = new Date().getTime()
    }

TotalTime = (end - start);//Total Time reset every time the function restart execution
```

We will get total time taken to execute the GetSomthing function on the variable "TotalTime".
When The GetSomthing function calls again the "TotalTime" Starts Again from Zero.
I need to save "TotalTime" to a variable that shows overall the Time taken by Main Function regardless of GetSomthing Function.

Can We save
`TotalTime = (end - start)`;  to an array and sum all  array values to a new variable?

Comment: `=+` should be `+=`, though that shouldnt give you a syntax error it should just set TotalDurationofExecution to TotalTime

Comment: Still Time reset to new

Comment: TotalTime reset on each execution, and TotalDurationofExecution doesn't. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: A very simple mod of my answer will allow you to get the total duration time of all of your global functions. Just let me know.

Comment: All i need is add TotalTime values to new Object  also when TotalTime get refresh the new TotalTime value to be added to previous object.

Comment: Please explain in layman's terms what you actaully want to accomplish. Your technical terms believe it or not aren't helping me to understand what you actually want the code to do. Also in order to reply to me, start off your comment with @JonathanGray otherwise I will not get the notification and may only end up finding that you've replied by pure chance (like just now).

Comment: @JonathanGray  Many Thanks for try to help me. I am noob on JS programming. i have updated the main question. please take a look at it.

Comment: @user3642342 Sorry for the late response. You're simply trying to keep track of the total amount of time your function runs for, correct? To do it simply, just remove this line in the code from my answer: `resultObj[i] = resultObj[i]/timeRecords[i].length;` (this will remove the total-to-average calculation, leaving just the total)

Answer (score 1):

I created a function for a similar question here on SO today. This one automatically calculates very accurate average execution times of global functions. You can modify it to suit your needs:

```
function testFunc(test) {
    for(var i=0;i<100000000;i++) { i = i+test; }
    };

function testFunc2(test) {
    for(var i=0;i<100000000;i++) { i = i+test; }
    };

var getPerfResults = (function(){
    var timeRecords = {}, xTr = 0, name;
    var setPerfRecords = function(oFn, fnIdentity) {
        timeRecords[fnIdentity] = [];
        return function(){
            var xTime = performance.now();
            var xResult = oFn.apply(this, arguments);
            xTime = performance.now()-xTime;
            timeRecords[fnIdentity].push(xTime);
            return xResult;
            };
        };
    for (name in window) {
        try { window[name]; // Security exception may occur here
        if (typeof window[name] === 'function')
            window[name] = setPerfRecords(window[name], name);
            }
        catch(err) { }
        }
    return function() {
        var resultObj = {}, n, i;
        for(i in timeRecords) {
            if(timeRecords.hasOwnProperty(i)
             && timeRecords[i].length > 0) {
                resultObj[i] = 0; 
                for(n=0;n<timeRecords[i].length;n++) {
                    resultObj[i] = resultObj[i]+timeRecords[i][n];
                    }
                resultObj[i] = resultObj[i]/timeRecords[i].length;
                }
            }
        return resultObj;
        };
    }());

testFunc(1);
testFunc(10);
testFunc(100);
testFunc(1000);
testFunc(10000);
testFunc2(0);

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getPerfResults());
```

Comment: Some browsers won't support the performance object. You can use this line of code first as a workaround to check if a workaround is needed and if so it applies it: `performance = window.performance?window.performance:{now: function(){return Date.now();}};`